# Can i use the Hugo Firth api wrapper with the artisan command?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mailchimp, laravel-artisan

i am using Hugo Firth API wrapper in my Laravel project for Mailchimp.
I know that the mainly use for it is in the controller. 
But i need to add mails to my Mailchimp list daily with cron job, which means that i need to use artisan command to do so.

can i just use the wrapper in the command as i use it in the controller?